# Gradient filling with PSTricks

Tags: pstricks, pst-grad

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
  \begin{pspicture}(2.4,0.6)
   \rput(1.2,0.25){Springboldene}
%   \psset{linestyle=none}
   \multido{\r=0.3+0.45}{5}{\pscircle(\r,0.3){0.3}}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How do I fill the five circles with a gradient color that stretches over all five of them, starting with orange at the left and going to green at the right?

I would like to remove the circles themselves (therefore `linestyle=none`) but fill the inner of them, as explained.

Comment: Do you want to fill each individual circle with a gradient, or should the gradient stretch over the total width of the five circles?

Comment: The gradient should strech over all five circles. (I'll specify it in my question.)

Comment: If you can construct the outline of the Audi logo then you can use a clip a gradient rectangle with that.

Comment: What does the Audi logo has to do with it? `:(` I would just like to have a gradient fill of the five circles.

Comment: @SvendMortensen Think of the five circles combined as in Jake's answer. The outline of five circles I mean. Well Audi logo + one more circle. :)

Comment: @percusse I see! I'm not interested in cars at all so I wasn't aware of that. `:)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{pst-grad,multido}   
\begin{document}

  \begin{pspicture}(-12ex,-3.5ex)(12ex,3.5ex)
  \pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=-90,
    gradbegin=orange!90!red,gradend=green!80!orange,
    gradmidpoint=0]{%
     \multido{\rA=-8+4}{5}{\pscircle(\rA ex,0){3ex}}}
  \rput(0,0){\large\textbf{Springboldene}}
  \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

and the same for a `gradmidpoint=0.5`

[image]

[image]

Comment: @SvendMortensen: There is also [`pst-slpe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-slpe) that provides `fillstyle=slope` (and friends).

Comment: @Werner Nice. I'll probably use this.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can do it using TikZ: The filling will stretch over all circles as long as they're specified using a single `\path` (or `\shade`) command

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade [left color=orange!90!red, right color=green!80!orange]
    \foreach \i in {-2,...,2}{
     (\i*3.5ex,0) circle [radius=2.5ex]
};
\node [font=\bfseries] (A) {Springboldene};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice. I would like to use PSTricks, though.

Comment: @SvendMortensen: Yes, sorry, your question is quite clear about that. It has just become customary that TikZ questions also get a PSTricks answer, and vice versa. I'm sure Herbert or KarlsStudents will come up with a PSTricks approach soon.

Comment: Have you pinged any of them? `:)`

Comment: @SvendMortensen: There's no global ping, unfortunately, but I think they monitor the {pstricks} tag quite closely.

Comment: Okay. If no PSTricks solution appears, I'll accept your answer (but you can always get an upvote, which you will).

Answer (score 2):

*My code seems to be verbose but the extra code is actually to get the precise dimension and placement. It also make you more convenient to adjust the parameters.*

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pst-grad}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}


\newpsstyle{A}
{
    fillstyle=gradient,
    gradbegin=red,
    gradend=yellow,
    gradangle=30,
    gradmidpoint=0.5,
}

\psset{linestyle=none}


\def\greeting{Springboldene}
\def\hoffset{5pt}
\def\voffset{5pt}



\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\raisebox{\depth}{\greeting}}

\newlength\Left
\newlength\Right
\newlength\Top
\newlength\Bottom


\Left=\dimexpr-0.5\wd\IBox-\hoffset
\Right=\dimexpr0.5\wd\IBox+\hoffset
\Top=\dimexpr0.5\ht\IBox+\voffset
\Bottom=\dimexpr-0.5\ht\IBox-\voffset

% for circles
\FPset\a{-27.00}
\FPset\b{27.00}
\FPset\N{7}
\FPeval\step{round((b-a)/N:2)}
\FPeval\NplusOne{N+1}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)
  \psclip{\pscustom{\multido{\nx=\a+\step}{\NplusOne}{\pscircle(\nx pt,0){8pt}}}}
      \psframe[style=A](\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top) 
    \endpsclip
    \rput(0,0){\usebox\IBox}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are too many circles

Comment: @Jake: I will adjust the parameters in the next update.

Comment: I cannot really follow what you are doing, but it looks fancy. `:)` Can you explain the code a bit, please?